# fabric.js canvas.on('mouse:down')

Tags: fabricjs

Im drawing elements to a new fabric.js canvas. Im using the following code to listen to click events

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
  console.log(options.target);

  if (options.target) {
     //get details of element
     var clicked_id= options.target.get('id')

     //before hide or move logs:
     //options -> Object {target: u, e: MouseEvent}

     //after hide or move logs:
     //options -> Object {target: undefined, e: MouseEvent}

  }

});
```

The problems comes, when I hide or move an element. The options parameter within the callback function doesn't recognize that the click X,Y was on top of an element, even if I do a canvas.renderall() call.

The only way I can get around this is to initize the canavs object again.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `canvas.calcOffset();`
after move and render

If it didn't work then try `.setCoords();`

Comment: thanks Yogesh, i ended up reverting to multiple divs for my end result and not using the canvas. This is a great heads up though, I will definatly revisit this library.